# Compile time constants wont work in mac os x in .net core

Tags: .net-core, .net-standard

So i'm currently trying to use compile time constants in my csproj using .net standard 2.0 with inspiration from here : https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/539

As you can see in the documentation $(OS) returns Unix for both Mac and Linux and I have some specific logic just for the Mac OS X. The $OS works fine. One solution would of course just be to do this on the runtime instead.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>

    <IsOSX Condition="'$([System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation]::IsOSPlatform($([System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform]::OSX)))' == 'true'">true</IsOSX>
    <IsLinux Condition="'$([System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation]::IsOSPlatform($([System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform]::Linux)))' == 'true'">true</IsLinux>
  </PropertyGroup>


  <Target Name="PrintRID" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Message Text="IsWindows $(IsWindows)" Importance="high" />
    <Message Text="IsOSX $(IsOSX)" Importance="high" />
    <Message Text="IsLinux $(IsLinux)" Importance="high" />
  </Target>
```

And this executes the correct output on build : Target PrintRID:
    IsWindows 
    IsOSX true
    IsLinux

But when i then try to use it as an constant it will not work.

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="$(IsOSX)">
    <DefineConstants>MACOSX</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Usage :

```
#if MACOSX
            return "OSX"; 
#elif WINDOWS
            return "Windows"; 
#elif LINUX
            return "Linux"; 
#endif
```

anyone have any good idea what i'm doing wrong? 
The `System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform.OSX)`
Also returns true.

Dotnet version is 2.1.4, with visual studio for mac at version 7.4.2, osx version 10.13.2

Just to be sure, here is my full csproj file :

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <PackageId>Nyranith.Internal</PackageId>
    <PackageVersion>$(VersionSuffix)</PackageVersion>
    <Authors>Nyranith</Authors>
    <Description></Description>
    <PackageRequireLicenseAcceptance>false</PackageRequireLicenseAcceptance>
    <Copyright></Copyright>
    <PackageTags></PackageTags>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>

    <IsOSX Condition="'$([System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation]::IsOSPlatform($([System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform]::OSX)))' == 'true'">true</IsOSX>
    <IsLinux Condition="'$([System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation]::IsOSPlatform($([System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform]::Linux)))' == 'true'">true</IsLinux>
  </PropertyGroup>


  <Target Name="PrintRID" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Message Text="IsWindows $(IsWindows)" Importance="high" />
    <Message Text="IsOSX $(IsOSX)" Importance="high" />
    <Message Text="IsLinux $(IsLinux)" Importance="high" />
  </Target>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="$(IsOSX)">
    <DefineConstants>MACOSX</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(OS)' == 'Unix'">
    <DefineConstants>UNIX</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>

   <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(OS)' == 'Windows_NT' ">
    <DefineConstants>WINDOWS_NT</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>

   <ItemGroup>
     <Folder Include="NewFolder\" />
   </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your condition might be wrong.

Try using this as the condition for your defines:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(IsOSX)'=='true'">
  <DefineConstants>MACOSX</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Can you share a detailed diagnostic log (and maybe a repro that I can look at)? I was able to get the project you describe above to work using this way of writing the properties.